# Setup UIActivityIndicatorView background

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am having trouble finding the appropriate solution for an activity indicator background. I would like to animate the activity indicator when the view controller loads, and **setup a gray transparent background for the entire view controller behind the indicator while it animates**. Once the indicator stops animating, the gray transparent background should be removed and the user should be able to resume interaction on the screen.

I figured that this is a standard in apps but I have not been able to find a good solution in Swift. Below is the code I have so far to setup the activity indicator:

```
let indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White
indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
indicator.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(indicator)
indicator.startAnimating()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UIView for background of indicator:

```
func showActivityIndicatory(uiView: UIView) {
    var container: UIView = UIView()
    container.frame = uiView.frame
    container.center = uiView.center
    container.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0xffffff, alpha: 0.3)

    var loadingView: UIView = UIView()
    loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
    loadingView.center = uiView.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0x444444, alpha: 0.7)
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    actInd.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle =
                UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    actInd.center = CGPointMake(loadingView.frame.size.width / 2,
                loadingView.frame.size.height / 2);
    loadingView.addSubview(actInd)
    container.addSubview(loadingView)
    uiView.addSubview(container)
    actInd.startAnimating()
}
```

Ref: https://coderwall.com/p/su1t1a/ios-customized-activity-indicator-with-swift

Comment: This is great, thanks. But, I'm not sure where/when to appropriately call this function so that it shows immediately when the view controller is displayed.

Comment: What do you want with indicator?

Comment: I would like to show the indicator and container view while I pull the data from the server, stop animating once those functions are complete, and then hide the container view and indicator. If you could please adapt your solution provided to that scenario, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, I hope it can help other users.
I am using Snapkit for the interface building

```
public class GenericView: UIView {

    private var spinerFlag: Bool = false

    internal lazy var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let activity = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
        activity.color = ThemeColor.defaultGreen
        return activity
    }()

    private lazy var spinnerBackground: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = ThemeColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        view.addSubview(self.spinner)
        return view
    }()


    ...


    // MARK: Spinner

    private func setupSpinner(){

        spinnerBackground.isHidden = true
        self.addSubview(spinnerBackground)
        spinnerBackground.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.height.equalTo(spinner.frame.width*2)
        }
        spinner.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerY.equalTo(spinnerBackground.snp.centerY)
            make.centerX.equalTo(spinnerBackground.snp.centerX)
        }
        self.spinerFlag = true
    }


    internal func spinnerIsHidden(state: Bool){

        if (!self.spinerFlag) {
            setupSpinner()
        }
        spinnerBackground.isHidden = state
    }

}
```

To run you just need to implement this UIViewController

```
public class GenericViewController: UIViewController {

   internal var contentView: GenericView

   public override func loadView() {

      let viewToShow = GenericView()
      self.view = self.contentView = viewToShow
   }

   internal func startSpinner() {
     contentView.spinnerIsHidden(state: false)
     contentView.spinner.startAnimating()
   }

   internal func stopSpinner() {
     contentView.spinnerIsHidden(state: true)
     contentView.spinner.stopAnimating()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is

Use **UIAlertController** and add **UIActivityIndicatorView** as a Subview to the AlertView.

**Advantage**

1. Simple implementation and no need to worry about auto orientation or
   rotation. **UIAlertController** will handle it automatically.
2. User interaction will be disabled automatically as its the default
   behaviour from AlertController

Or Else - If you want custom controls use ready made utilities that already available for the same purpose from CocoaPods.